# Custom authentication filter hook isn't working, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a problem with this code, it's not working. I don't know what I need to do to fix it. Can you guys help me?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: m0ri-login-math
 */

function m0ri_login_math()
{
    session_start();
    $randomNumber1 = rand(0,99);
    $randomNumber2 = rand(0,99);
    
    ?>

    <label> result this operation <?php echo $randomNumber1 . ' + ' . $randomNumber2; ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" size="20" />
    <?php
    $result = $randomNumber1 + $randomNumber2;
    $value = $_GET['result'];

    $_SESSION["result"] = $result;
    $_SESSION["value"] = $value;
    
}

add_action( 'login_form' , 'm0ri_login_math' );
add_filter( 'authenticate', function( $user )
{
    session_start();
    $result = $_SESSION["result"];
    $value = $_SESSION["value"];

    if($result == $value)
    {
        return new WP_User($user);
    }else {
        return new WP_Error('error' , 'error plugin');
    }
    return $user;
} , 999 );
```

I want to display a textbox on `/wp-login` where the user must enter a correct answer of `$randomNumber1 + $randomNumber2`. Then in the [authenticate](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/) filter hook check if the value from the textbox equals the expected result and if so the user may enter website, else they may not enter.

Comment: `$_GET['result']` inside the login form will save null into the session value. Try to move the $_GET into the authenticate filter instead. You're mixing requests, you won't get the submitted value in `login_form`. You'll get it later, during a POST request. Also it's a POST request, $_GET will be empty.

Comment: thank for ur help it work
i just transfer POST method to authenticate filter and problem solve <3